# If mySQL field is blank, insert value

Tags: mysql

In my mySQL table, I have a 'reportstatus' column.  I have some values in this column already, however I need to update the column so that if any field in the column is empty, the value will be 'Pending'.

I have no clue how to write this script.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try something -- this is a pretty basic `update` statement with a `where` clause . . .

Comment: Why bother? In your code or sql decode the null value to a reporting status

Comment: I don't know mySQL, I am sure its basic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE `mySQL` SET `reportstatus`='Pending' WHERE `reportstatus` IS NULL OR `reportstatus`=''
```